# nginx wordpress wp-admin redirecting to home

Tags: wordpress, nginx

On my nginx server when i visit example.com/wp-admin or example.com/login i always see the home page of my site, but when i visit example.com/wp-login.php everything works (and login screen is showed).

Is there some config to do in nginx to make these urls (/wp-admin or wp-login) work again?

Note: Other posts permalinks like example.com/hello-world is working.

My configs files are:

**1. /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**2. /etc/nginx/sites-available/worpdress.conf**

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    #server_name 127.0.0.1;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location /robots.tx {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
                 deny all;
        }

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**3. /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf**

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to have a missing `/` in your `try_files` statement. It should be:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

The second term (`$uri/`) should cause the URI `/wp-admin` to be redirected to `/wp-admin/` and then invoke the file `/wp-admin/index.php`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was solved with your tip!